# Show popup at the center of screen

Tags: leaflet

Currently, after an event I show the user a popup. However I do it as shown in the tutorial, by putting in the coordinates where the popup should show:

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

The problem with this is that I have to fly the user to a predetermined place (incase they not in view of where the marker will be put) so they can see the popup.

What if I just want the popup to show in the center of the user viewport?

Comment: It's not clear if you want a popup (as per the title) or a marker (as per the code snippet). Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply retrieve the lat/lng position of the current map view center, using [`map.getCenter()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getcenter):

> Returns the geographical center of the map view

Example:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

setTimeout(function() {
  var currentViewCenter = map.getCenter();
  L.marker(currentViewCenter).addTo(map);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```